# Making input form rotate in 3d using WPF (like silverlight planeprojection)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, 3d

I am looking at updating the UI of one of my projects that currently uses Winforms and i was hoping to use WPF. I have used silverlight for a while and wanted to use the same PlaneProjection effects to basically rotate my form (by form i mean a group of input controls) along the Y axis.

After looking over the interwebs it looks like for some reason WPF doesnt support this kind of  usage with 2d controls like silverlight does, however after scouring i managed to find Thriple, which looked like it was what i wanted, however i find trying to create my UI in the XAML editor a nightmare with it as it seems to stretch and skew everything and ignores the width/heights as if it is automatically scaling everything.

I was wondering if there was anything else that would allow me to do what i want, ideally i would also like it to support WindowsFormHost controls as i have some winform controls that i would like to continue using. It seems a bit silly that silverlight does EXACTLY what i want, but the main technology it is based upon doesnt...

Any alternatives would be great, i just want something that will let me rotate and translate my controls in 3d space and still allow the user to interact with the control.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's as easy to do in WPF, but its definitely possible.  You'd have to use the Viewport2DVisual3D class inside a Viewport3d.

Comment: Thanks will check it out, will leave the accepted answer for a while though incase there are any other answers.

Comment: Just tried using Viewport2DVisual3D class and it just distorts all content, so text that is of size 10 gets skewed and appears to look narrow and size 15, i can adjust the camera position to make it look a bit more normal but all the controls just collapse and doesnt look right, currently Planerator looks like the best option but i cant see how to scale within it...